# Restler3- POST Upload (zip) Files

Tags: post, file-upload, readonly

I really enjoy Restler3, but now there is a problem.
I want to POST a ZIP file to the server. Just by a simple HTML-Form.
To enable the upload if have to add

```
$restler->setSupportedFormats('UploadFormat');
```

But if do that all the JSON-GET-Requests just won't work.

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Luracast\Restler\RestException' with message 'UploadFormat is read only…
```

That's the error-message. What should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. Changing my code to this worked:

```
$r->setSupportedFormats('UploadFormat','JsonFormat');
```